# Define a static class variable on javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm starting using the new way of OO in javascript by following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) tutorial. This new way of OO of javascript follows the [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions) specification.

Follows a sample of my code:

```
class SomeClass{

        static SomeFunction(data){
            this.data = data;
        }

}
```

What I want is to make the variable `this.data` static.

Is any way that I could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the new class keyword is just syntatic sugar you can do

```
SomeClass.staticVariableName = value;
```

Put this outside of the class, if you put it in the constructor, then it will only be initialized when you create at least 1 instance.

Side note: if this is a client side code, then I just want to warn you that you shouldn't authenticate people client side, because it's terribly insecure.

Comment: It is just an example: this not really "match" with a really case. I ask this because the tutorial does not explain it. Maybe is better change the case to become more understandable.

I will test and see the if results

Comment: @Ricardo Again, I just wanted to warn you if you intended this code for production

Comment: Thank you :) It Works for me